# Configuring a dTPM chip on Raspberry pi running Windows IoT Core

Tags: raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10, tpm

I am a beginner on all IoT related things. Hence, sorry in advance for all the experts I might annoy, and thanks for your patience.

I provisioned my rpi3 to azure with a simulated TPM. But now I've purchased a TPM SLM 9670 chip and attached it to the pi.
The goal is to use this TPM to provision the pi to Azure. So I followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/secure-your-device/setuptpm#setup-discrete-tpm-dtpm)

To break down my approach w.r.t link I was following,

Step 1 done.
Step 2,3 skipped as I'm using an rp3.
Step 4: "Based on your discrete TPM module of choice, identify its matching ACPI table here.".. I have no idea how to find a matching ACPI. So I did trial and error with every ACPITABL.dat file in the given [repo](https://github.com/ms-iot/security/tree/master/TPM-ACPITABL) (Step 5). Note that I already had a ACPITABL.dat in the system32 folder. I took a back up of that before replacing it with the ACPITABL.dat file from the repo.
Step 6 Done
Step 7 Done
Step 8 When I run t2t.exe -cap ERROR(0x8028400f): Tbsi_GetDeviceInfo() failed. (This happened for all the ACPITABL.dat files I copy pasted in Step 5). Replacing the original ACPITABL.dat file that was in the sys32 folder and running the t2t.exe -cap command results in the following.

TBS detected 2.0 simulated TPM (sTPM).
Capabilities:
PT_FIXED:
TPM_PT_FAMILY_INDICATOR = '2.0

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to re-flash the image of Windows IoT Core to test the issue?

Comment: Hi Michael,

I actually got the pi to recognize the dTPM after all. In the steps given in the link, I didn't perform the actions in step 6 every time I did trial and error with a new ACPITABL.dat file. So I tried all over again, but this time I did step 6 every time I used a new ACPITABL.dat file. Finally it worked for the ACPI table under SPI0CS1.

Comment: Please refer to the topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/195383/configuring-a-dtpm-chip-on-raspberry-pi-running-wi.html).

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT That's me asking the question there as well Michael :D